# Using a WCFService to kick off a program on different machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I've followed these two walk-throughs:

- http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-wcf-web-service-in.html
- http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.com/2012/01/cnet-how-to-consume-web-service-in-cnet.html

Application X on machine X can now send a string to application Y on machine Y which returns a string back to X.

I was hoping the string could effectively act as an instruction to run a much bigger job on Y.

So really the client on X wants to send the string and then close; as the process on Y takes 10mins. Currently though the console is waiting for the WCFService to return back a string - how do I get X to just send the string and then close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service interface do something like this...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void IAmALongRunningMethodAndIDontCareToReturnAnything();
}
```

That will cause the client that calls the method 'IAmALongRunningMethodAndIDontCareToReturnAnything' to return immediately

Comment: currently I'm testing: so the long running method isn't so long running - is it easy for me to make the method oause for 2mins to prove to myself that this is working ok?

Comment: just did it  - seems to work. initially I tried `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);` and then used a `stopwatch` to do `string t = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();` and write that to the database from the long running method - and it threw an exception; but I changed it to `string t = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();` and 10seconds later it popped up in the databse. Wonder what the exception was about?

Comment: Not really enough information there to tell you. What was the exception?